# Unable to fill more than 1 combo box using following method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am filling up my combobox with information from my database when the program starts by using the following method. It works fine when I use it to fill one combo box. But if I use it to fill more than one combo box, it returns an error XAMLParseException. Please advice what is wrong. Thanks.

```
public void fillCombo(string query, string name, ComboBox c)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmdReader = new MySqlCommand(query,conn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            myReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader(); 

            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                string temp = myReader.GetString(name);
                c.Items.Add(temp); 
            }
        }

//If I call to fill one combo box it works
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fillCombo("SELECT * FROM Jobs;", "Job_ID", comboBoxJobID); 
}

//If I call to fill multiple comboboxes, it returns the error.
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fillCombo("SELECT * FROM Departments;", "Dept_ID", comboBoxDeptID);
    fillCombo("SELECT * FROM Jobs;", "Job_ID", comboBoxJobID);
    fillCombo("SELECT * FROM Missions;", "Mission_ID", comboBoxMissionID);  
}
```

Comment: Check for inner exception and post it here. Also XAML code.

Comment: is it only happens when you add multiple? did you check specific query individual ? can you send us string representation of the result of the 3 queries ?

Comment: Yes checked all 3 queries individually. The string representation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close your reader. Try the following.

```
public void fillCombo(string query, string name, ComboBox c)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmdReader = new MySqlCommand(query,conn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            myReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader(); 

            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                string temp = myReader.GetString(name);
                c.Items.Add(temp); 
            }
        }
        myReader.Close();
```